# is there a way i can fix my api request issue?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I did this but the (`endPointUrl`) after `await get`, is showing error, and having being have lot of issue, in which any url I use never responds always showing failed to locate localhost

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:NewsApp/model/article_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class ApiService {

  final endPointUrl =
      "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=6ef7ae62a9e74ca2bcc7d634f9985146";

  Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
    Response res = await get(endPointUrl);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];

      List<Article> articles =
          body.map((dynamic item) => 
        Article.fromJson(item)).toList();

      return articles;
    } else {
      throw ("Can't get the Articles");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *is showing error* is useless as a problem description unless you tell us specifically what that *error* is, including the **exact, complete error message**.  The same goes with *being have lot of issue* when you don't tell us specifically what the *issue* are that you're having. Please [edit] your post and be more specific and clear.

Comment: Change `get(endPointUrl)` to this `get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl))`

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch method should be like this,

To fetch the whole data present in the given URL so use it where ever you want.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:NewsApp/model/article_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {

    final endPointUrl =
          "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=6ef7ae62a9e74ca2bcc7d634f9985146";
    
   static   Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
        Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl));
    
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
         List json = jsonDecode(res.body);
    
         // List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];
    
           return
              json .map((dynamic item) => 
            Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
    
          //return articles;
        } else {
          throw ("Can't get the Articles");
        }
      }
}
```

now suppose you retrieve the data in the following way.

```
 FutureBuilder List<Article>(
                            future: ApiService.getArticle(),
                                
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {


                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return ListView.bilder(
itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
itemBuilder: (context, position){
return Text(snapshot.data[position].article);
}

);
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text('error occurred');
                              } else {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }
                            },
                          ),
```